# Density plot for truncated data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to draw the density of a truncated variable. The data can be either bounded from below or from both sides.
For example,

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.normal(size=1000000)
data[data < 0] = 0
data[data > 1] = 1
sns.kdeplot(data)
```

How can I draw the density such that there is no probability mass outside the boundaries?

Comment: See this blog post for a very good writeup on how to do this http://thirdorderscientist.org/homoclinic-orbit/2013/10/24/kernel-density-estimation-for-random-variables-with-bounded-support-mdash-the-transformation-trick

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into that.

Comment: The seaborn `kdeplot` function uses a gaussian kernel density estimate. If your data are bounded between 0 and 1, they are probably not gaussian, and you should use a different method to visualize the distribution.

Comment: Any alternative to `kdeplot` with truncated data? I only think about plotting an histograms with many bins...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `clip` kwarg?

From the [docs for `kdeplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html):

> **clip** : pair of scalars, or pair of pair of scalars, optional
>
> Lower and upper bounds for datapoints used to fit KDE. Can provide a pair of
>   (low, high) bounds for bivariate plots.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.normal(size=1000000)
lower,upper = 0,1
sns.kdeplot(data,clip=(lower,upper))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If the data is bounded between 0 and 1 I don't want to see a line outside the range.

Comment: @BayerSe did you find any solution for that?